# Reading feed in php

Tags: php

I am reading xml feed with the following code:

```
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($x -> channel -> item);
    die;
```

The problem is that in `$x -> channel -> item` i am getting only first array element of item. When I use,

```
   foreach($x -> channel -> item as $entry) {
        // code
    }
```

then all items are listed. I just need the clarification that from the above code why all items cannot be read without the `foreach` loop.

Comment: They can. You could use a `for` or a `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour will differ based on which version of PHP you're using.

**Different outcomes on different versions of PHP**

For example this example code

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement("<xml>
  <channel>
    <item>baz</item>
    <item>bax</item>
    <item>bay</item>
  </channel>
</xml>");

print_r($x -> channel -> item);
```

Running on `php 5.2.17` will display the first item:

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/B2DyFE

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => baz )
```

Whereas this code running on the latest development version `php 5.5-dev` will output all the elements.

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/z3ML9n

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => baz [1] => bax [2] => bay )
```

**The reason this works when you iterate over it with a foreach** is the SimpleXMLElement implements Traversable [as documented here](http://php.net/simplexmlelement), so the foreach will access the elements that way, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Well `$x->channel->item` is [array-like](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) so to get each item, it makes sense to iterate over it with a foreach or some other loop.

To get individual elements directly for example you could do:

```
echo $x->channel->item[0];
echo $x->channel->item[1];
```